# What is the effect of adding new word vector embeddings onto an existing embedding space for Neural networks

Tags: neural-network, word2vec, word-embedding

In Word2Vector, the word embeddings are learned using co-occurrence and updating the vector's dimensions such that words that occur in each other's context come closer together.

My questions are the following:

1) If you already have a pre-trained set of embeddings, let's say a 100 dimensional space with 40k words, can you add 10 additional words onto this embedding space without changing the existing word embeddings. So you would only be updating the dimensions of the new words using the existing word embeddings. I'm thinking of this problem with respect to the  "word 2 vector" algorithm, but if people have insights on how GLoVe embeddings work in this case, I am still very interested.

2) Part 2 of the question is; Can you then use the NEW word embeddings in a NN that was trained with the previous embedding set and expect reasonable results. For example, if I had trained a NN for sentiment analysis, and the word "nervous" was previously not in the vocabulary, then would "nervous" be correctly classified as "negative".

This is a question about how sensitive (or robust) NN are with respect to the embeddings. I'd appreciate any thoughts/insight/guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial training used info about known words to plot them in a useful N-dimensional space.

It is of course theoretically possible to then use new information, about new words, to also give them coordinates in the same space. You would want lots of varied examples of the new words being used together with the old words.

Whether you want to freeze the positions of old words, or let them also drift into new positions based on the new examples, could be an important choice to make. If you've already trained a pre-existing classifier (like a sentiment classifier) using the older words, and didn't want to re-train that classifier, you'd probably want to lock the old words in place, and force the new words into compatible positioning (even if the newer combined text examples would otherwise change the relative positions of older words).

Since after an effective train-up of the new words, they should generally be near similar-meaning older words, it would be reasonable to expect classifiers that worked on the old words to still do something useful on the new words. But how well that'd work would depend on lots of things, including how well the original word-set covered all the generalizable 'neighborhoods' of meaning. (If the new words bring in shades of meaning of which there were no examples in the old words, that area of the coordinate-space may be impoverished, and the classifier may have never had a good set of distinguishing examples, so performance could lag.)

Comment: I was hoping for what you said to be the general consensus before I pursue this idea further. I think what you said about needing the original word-set to cover the "generalizable neighborhoods of meaning" for the classifier makes great sense. Is that a commonly used phrase "generalizable neighborhoods of meaning" ?, it makes perfect sense when I think about it.

Comment: I don't think it's common, but it's a way I think about it. To an extent, the training process uses the full space to get as good at the internal prediction task as possible, but within the range of meanings that its training texts provide. If learning 'hot' and 'cold' from just physics texts, the words and directions will be spaced for that domain... but if later forcing emotional/fictional texts into that same anchored space, the new words/senses related to 'hot' and 'cold' moods may not have as much freedom to position themselves in usefully contrasting ways.